# MySQL syntax to generate binary structure

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table as shown in the image. I want to generate output for the given user like if I select "aswarojgar" then I want to fetch all the user who comes under "aswarojgar"

output example for "aswarojgar"

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      email          |     side         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Mukesh123       |         left     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Poonam123       |         left     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Pravin123       |         right    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Kamal123        |         left     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Babi123         |         right    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

i want to create a structure like this

```
         aswarojgar
          /        \ 
     Mukesh123       
       /      \          
 Poonam123    Pravin123            
  /      \     /      \ 
Kamal123             Babi123
```

Comment: select email, side from your_tab where not email = "aswarojgar"

Comment: Use sub query to get id of row with email = "aswarojgar" and then get all those whose id is greater than subquery id.

Comment: you should engineer it more, make a group for members

Comment: it not working . can you suggest SQL syntax.

Comment: I would suggest you create a column to store the parent_id and then generate SQL procedure based on the child traversal logic

Comment: Paul Spiegel, Nick if look carefully both questions is different.if you cant suggest the answer then please don't try to avoid the question.